# Is there any way to increase code intellisense height in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Is there any way to increase code intellisense height on  ASP.NET?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intellisense pop-up window is resizable.  It will let you increase the vertical height to display a maximum of 16 suggestions (and a minimum of 5).  Once the pop-up is visible, hover your mouse over the bottom right corner and you will see the arrow cursor that indicates that you can click and drag to adjust the size of the pop-up.

Comment: All i am seeing 11 item and can't resize it. Is there any registry setting?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When the intellisense box is displayed, you can use your mouse to resize the box to an extent. There is a limit to how big or small you can make it, but you can resize it both vertically or horizontally.