# is there a way to change height of intellisense popup in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Intellisense popup in VS2010 is driving me crazy.

I can only see 9 items at a time in the intellisense popup.

It really makes browsing classes you're not familiar with a lot harder.

[In VS2008 you could resize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971854/is-there-any-way-to-increase-code-intellisense-height-in-visual-studio).

is there a trick to this - or a connect issue someone has already made?

**VS2010 Quickwatch: 23 items**

**VS2010 Main editor: 9 items**

---

[alt text http://www.rollingrazor.com/content/images/temp/intellisense_popup.png](http://www.rollingrazor.com/content/images/temp/intellisense_popup.png)

**Edit:** Here's an image. Maximum of 9 items in C# window, but 23 in the quickwatch. Huge productivity difference. Especially since the intellisense popup now does partial matching and not just the beginning of the string.

Comment: i worked with a new window,

    window.open('Default.aspx', 'NewWindow' , 'top=100, left=100, width=400, height=450')

maybe it works with pop up too, but i dont know

Comment: @tyzak. i'm talking about the VS2010 IDE itself, not in a web browser - but thanks anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems liek this won't be fixed

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/474009/intellitype-list-has-max-height

**Vote for it !**

Comment: I've written a begging email to ScottGu on this one. Seems like a simple fix to allow for 15, 20 items. If people don't like it they can just hit Escape !

Comment: Scott responded and passed it on. Fingers crossed !

Comment: unfortuntately pretty definitely won't be 'fixed' in VS2010 RC. btw. changing font size of the intellisense text doesn't give you more items :-(

Comment: fortunately i've noticed the more familiar I get with an API the less I need a long intellisense list. it is still annoying though. presumably those developers actually creating Visual Studio are very familiar with the APIs. switching around between Silverlight/WPF/WCF etc. was very frustrating. microsoft just has a really poor history of making dialog boxes too small even in mature developer tools. take a look at the indexes window in Sql Server for instance. hopefully the 9 votes this has got in connect will one day count for something!a

Answer (score 2):

It isn't resizable (I just spoke to the main developer that works on it).  I'm told that the size is fixed mostly for performance reasons, and that there really isn't a way to change this with an extension, as the size calculation is somewhat complicated (it doesn't actually know how big it needs to be until the first time it is shown).

If you feel very strongly that this should be changed, can you [file a bug on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback)? That's the best way to give feedback about it, and allow other people to vote on it. It'll likely be immediately `Won't Fix`ed for VS2010, but it may get considered for future releases.

Comment: i feel very strongly! In Silverlight the DataGrid class has about 171 members. This is 20 pages of intellisense!!! I've written a begging email to ScottGu on this one! The connect issue was resolved as won't fix. I don't know how well you know the main developer but I just want to make it clear that I don't care about a resizable (by dragging) popup - I just want 15, 20, 30 items in the list by default. thanks!

Comment: The problem with defaulting to 15/20/30 items is the performance issue; from what I understand, 9 was a trade-off in showing as much information as possible as fast as possible.  That's an especially hard tradeoff if only some users want the larger size, whereas it seems all users want completion to be fast :)

I'm sure it'll get looked at for the next release, and they'll see if there is anything they can do to perhaps make the size configurable in *some* way.

Comment: Anyone know if this has been fixed in VS2012 RC?

Comment: Performance? Maybe in 2010, but does it still? Android Studio (written in that slow Java) allows resizing the code completion pop-up, and I do not feel much of a difference in terms of speed. Maybe something like 0.5 seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

They could simply provide a

#### "more..."

element at the bottom of the list. For those who need it, the extra steps and wait would be more than worth the price.

Comment: it is already resizable. they just need to make the maximum height taller. this seems like added complexity. the whole benefit of having it long is that you can instantly find what you want. i don't think an extra click would be useful - but perhaps a 'more' button that would show some kind of expanded window with the doc comments for each method would be useful