# Can I make autocomplete in Visual Studio longer?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2012

When I press `.` or `->` in C++ in VS 11 beta it shows me an autocomplete with 9 elements. Can I tell VS to show me more, maybe 20 elements? I tried searching tools->options but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation of Visual Studio (since 2010) and can't be changed.  Similar question here: [is there a way to change height of intellisense popup in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2362272/63179)